# I want output to be in csv when I query SOLR , but output still comes in javabin

Tags: java, csv, solr

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.add("wt","csv");
server.query(query);
```

In QueryResponse object params come out to be  params{q=*:*,**wt=javabin**,version=2}

Even though I  have set wt as csv in code above . Any way how to get solr output in csv ?

Answer (score 2):

The `solrj` Java library only supports `javabin` and `xml`.

You can use `HttpSolrServer#setParser(ResponseParser processor)` to define the format. The `wt` parameter won't work here.

If you want a csv output you have to manually transform the response from Solr to the csv format.